# Python strftime %A fixed length

Tags: python, date, format, strftime

I am using the following date format:

```
d.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y %H:%m")
```

and since the length of the weekday (`%A`) changes,
I would like to always print the weekday with 
10 characters, pad spaces to the left, and align it right.

Something like

```
d.strftime("10%A, %d %B %Y %H:%m")
```

What is the simplest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
d.strftime("%A") + " " * (10 - len(d.strftime("%A")) + "," + d.strftime("%d %B %Y %H:%m")
```

Jack

Answer (score 2):

[`str.rjust(10)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) does exactly that:

```
s = d.strftime('%A').rjust(10) + d.strftime(', %d %B %Y %H:%M')
```

It is likely that you want [%M (minutes), not %m (months)](http://strftime.org/) in your format string as [@Ahmad pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201605/python-strftime-a-fixed-length/35226085#comment67236284_35226085).

In Python 3.6+, to get a more concise version, one can abuse nested f-strings:

```
>>> f"{f'{d:%A}':>10}, {d:%d %B %Y %H:%M}"
'    Friday, 15 December 2017 21:31'
```

---

Prefer standard time formats such as rfc 3339:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z'
'2016-02-05T14:00:43.089828Z'
```

Or rfc 2822:

```
>>> from email.utils import formatdate
>>> formatdate(usegmt=True)                                          
'Fri, 05 Feb 2016 14:00:51 GMT'
```

instead.

Comment: Using python 3.5.2, I have to use %M (capital M). Otherwise, minutes is always 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly equivalent to [jfs's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35226085/241211) but you can [use `.format()`](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align) to make it slightly shorter:

```py
s = '{:>10}, {:%d %B %Y %H:%m}'.format(d.strftime('%A'), d)
```

or if you're putting more than just the date into the string:

```py
args = {
    'weekday': d.strftime('%A'),
    'date': d,
    'foo': some_other_stuff(),
    'bar': 17.5422,
}
s = '{weekday:>10}, {date:%d %B %Y %H:%m} {foo} {bar:>3.2f}'.format(**args)
```